# CRM 2011 Managed Properties - how to protect existing un-managed solutions?

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a `CRM 2011` managed solution that includes some changes to a standard entity (account) - i.e. new form and some extra fields. In most cases, we can install without a problem as the changes are merged. However we have encountered some instances where a client has renamed the Account entity to something else (Company) as an unmanaged chage (including view names) and our solution changes the entity name and view changes back to 'Account' when installed, based on the 'last one wins' rule.

My question is, is it possible to protect un-managed changes, so that we do not overwrite un-merged changes? i.e. similar to Managed Properties?

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible although maybe I don't fully understand what you are aiming to do.  When you export a solution it will save a snapshot of all the included components.  When you reimport, it should set all of the included components as they were when you exported them.  If you exported the account entity with a customized name, what sort of logic would you want in place to disallow that change to be imported?

If anyone else has a solution to this, I'd be glad to see it but I haven't come across one yet.

Comment: Hi Cole,I was hoping it might be possible to set the entity display name to readonly on the external app, prior to installing our managed solution. This is available from the 'Managed Properties' for custom entities and only takes affect once the solution is exported as a managed solution. Unfortunately, the entity display name has been renamed on an external system as an unmanaged change by another vendor. The only work-around I can think of at the moment is to make the same entity name change in our solution, but would like to avoid creating seperate solutions for different apps if possible.